# Tumblr image inappropriate cropping

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr, crop

I need my images to appear with its original ratio on my tumblr posts, but for some reason they lose a little bit of their bottom when stacked with multiple images. I'm no programmer, my limited knowledge allowed me to find where the code for that might be but I don't know how to program it to fix this issue.

Here's an image demonstrating the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta0Tm.jpg

Where I think the code might be:

```
</script>

    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/2XXmyt1i0/jquery.colorbox.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wofln30/lFrmyt0d1/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.photoset').photosetGrid({
      highresLinks: true,
      rel: 'withhearts-gallery',
      gutter: '5px',



      onComplete: function(){
        $('.photoset-grid-lightbox').attr('style');
        $('.photoset-grid-lightbox a.photoset-cell').colorbox({
          transition: "none",
          photo: true,
          scalePhotos: true,
          maxHeight:'90%',
          maxWidth:'90%'
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for eventual "noobiness", feel free to call me out on that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sadly the cropping is intentional: https://github.com/stylehatch/photoset-grid/blob/master/jquery.photoset-grid.js#L220

Comment: @mikedidthis thanks for the welcome and the info! weird that this was done intentionally, is there a way to change it? Cheers!

Comment: No problem. Depends on your situation. If you are stacking the photos (one above the other) its possible to fudge with CSS. Otherwise you will need to use another plugin.

Comment: @mikedidthis it might be the case of another plugin then, if you happen to know a few suggestions and it's not imposing I'll be happy to try.

Comment: You could give this one a try: https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset It crops from the center if the images in a row are different heights, but it they are the same, you *should* be ok.

Comment: @mikedidthis thank you very much for your attention! I'll give it a try as soon as I get some work done and will report back. really appreciate your responses as this was bugging me a lot, my limited knowledge made it almost impossible to know where to even start. cheers!

Comment: Honestly not a problem. Any issues let me know and I will take a look.

Comment: @mikedidthis Really appreciate it man! I tried using the one you suggested but didn't seem to work, it's obviously something I'm doing wrong. If you want to take a look at my blog so you can find the whole code, feel free to do so, it's at www.felipecunha.com Whenever you have the time of course, no hurry whatsoever. Thanks!